# how to upgrade iptables or add modules to iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables

i  am using linux version 2.6.30 in linksys x3500 i want to add statistic and length modules iptables version is 1 .4.0 my router commands looks like this:

```
help logout exit quit reboot adsl xdslctl xtm brctl cat loglevel logdest
virtualserver ddns df dumpcfg dumpmdm meminfo psp kill dnsproxy syslog echo 
ifconfig ping ps pwd sntp sysinfo tftp wlctl wifidefault arp defaultgateway
dhcpserver dns endbg dac3120_dbg hw_button_test lan lanhosts passwd ppp
restoredefault route save swversion cfgupdate swupdate exitOnIdle wan 7sl
sysreport tr69cfg aye_wireless aye_wan aye_ppp aye_atm aye_dhcpserver
aye_defaultgateway aye_dns aye_eth gui hnap_mutex_lock wl_channel_country
uctt_upnp_version consoledebug
```

and busybox command looks like this:

Built-in commands:

```
. : break cd continue eval exec exit export help login newgrp
read readonly set shift times trap umask wait [ busybox cat chmod
chrt cp cut date deluser df dirname dmesg du echo expr false
fdisk flash_eraseall ftpget ifconfig init insmod kill killall
klogd linuxrc ln logger logread ls md5sum mkdir mknod mount msh
netstat nptest ping ping6 ps pwd reboot rm rmmod route sed sendarp
sh sleep sync sysinfo syslogd tee test tftp tftpd top traceroute
traceroute6 true tty umount uname vconfig wget
```

Comment: You need to upgrade the kernel, and possibly add modules. What Linux distribution do you have on the linksys? OpenWRT? Something else?

Comment: You're not actually including your question in your body. Check out the help section on [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Routers are usually restricted so you might to either upgrade the image or switch to a different one.

Comment: dirtkt  i am using this version Linux version 2.6.30 (root@owen-desktop) (gcc version 4.4.2 (Buildroot 2010.02-git) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 22 15:52:21 CST 2013 this is linux that came with router

Comment: seth ok i will check it